# How to check if the threads have completed its task or not?

Tags: java, multithreading

OK, I created couples of threads to do some complex task. Now How may I check each threads whether it has completed successfully or not??

```
class BrokenTasks extends Thread {
     public BrokenTasks(){
       super();
     }
    public void run(){
     //Some complex tasks related to Networking..
     //Example would be fetching some data from the internet and it is not known when can it be finished
      }
      }


    //In another class 
    BrokenTasks task1 = new BrokenTasks();
    BrokenTasks task2 = new BrokenTasks();
    BrokenTasks task3 = new BrokenTasks();
    BrokenTasks task4 = new BrokenTasks();
    task1.start();
    .....
    task4.start();
```

So how can I check if these all tasks completed successfully from 
     i) Main Program (Main Thread)
     ii)From each consecutive threads.For example: checking if task1 had ended or not  from within task2..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to use threads is not to use them, directly. Instead make a thread pool. Then in your POJO task encapsulation have a field that is only set at the end of computation.

There might be 3-4 milliseconds delay when another thread can see the status - but finally the JVM makes it so. As long as other threads do not over write it. That you can protect by making sure each task has a unique instance of work to do and status, and other threads only poll that every 1-5 seconds or have a listener that the worker calls after completion. 
A library I have used is my own
https://github.com/tgkprog/ddt/tree/master/DdtUtils/src/main/java/org/s2n/ddt/util/threads

To use : in server start or static block :

```
package org.s2n.ddt.util;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;

import org.s2n.ddt.util.threads.PoolOptions;
import org.s2n.ddt.util.threads.DdtPools;

public class PoolTest {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PoolTest.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        PoolOptions options = new PoolOptions();
        options.setCoreThreads(2);
        options.setMaxThreads(33);
        DdtPools.initPool("a", options);
        Do1 p = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            p = new Do1();
            DdtPools.offer("a", p);

        }
        LangUtils.sleep(3 + (int) (Math.random() * 3));
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(p);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Do1.getLs(), 10);
    }

}

class Do1 implements Runnable {
    volatile static long l = 0;

    public Do1() {
        l++;

    }

    public void run() {

        // LangUtils.sleep(1 + (int) (Math.random() * 3));
        System.out.println("hi " + l);
    }

    public static long getLs() {
        return l;
    }
}
```

Things you should not do:
* Don't do things every 10-15 milliseconds 
* Unless academic do not make your own thread
* don't make it more complex then it needs for 97% of cases

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer a little more ? Like adding sample code for using  thread pool...

Comment: Updated answer will notice no new threads being made by app code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Callable` and `ForkJoinPool` for this task.

```
class BrokenTasks implements Callable {
    public BrokenTasks(){
       super();
    }
    public Object call() thrown Exception {
     //Some complex tasks related to Networking..
     //Example would be fetching some data from the internet and it is not known when can it be finished
    }
}


//In another class 
BrokenTasks task1 = new BrokenTasks();
BrokenTasks task2 = new BrokenTasks();
BrokenTasks task3 = new BrokenTasks();
BrokenTasks task4 = new BrokenTasks();

ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
Future result1 = pool.submit(task1);
Future result2 = pool.submit(task2);
Future result3 = pool.submit(task3);
Future result4 = pool.submit(task4);

value4 = result4.get();//blocking call
value3 = result3.get();//blocking call
value2 = result2.get();//blocking call
value1 = result1.get();//blocking call
```

And don't forget to shutdown pool after that.

Answer (score 1):

If a thread has not been completed its task then it is still alive. So for testing whether the thread has completed its task you can use `isAlive()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Classically you simply join on the threads you want to finish.  Your thread does not proceed until join completes.  For example:

```
// await all threads
task1.join();
task2.join();
task3.join();
task4.join();
// continue with main thread logic
```

(I probably would have put the tasks in a list for cleaner handling)

Answer (score 1):

#### There are two different questions here

One is if the thread still working.
The other one is if the task still not finished.

Thread is a very expensive method to solve problem, when we start a thread in java, the VM has to store context informations and solve synchronize problems(such as lock). So we usually use thread pool instead of directly thread. The benefit of thread pool is that we can use few thread to handle many different tasks. That means few threads keeps alive, while many tasks are finished.

#### Don’t find task status from a thread.

Thread is a worker, and tasks are jobs.
A thread may work on many different jobs one by one.
I don’t think we should ask a worker if he has finished a job. I’d rather ask the job if it is finished.

When I want to check if a job is finished, I use signals.

#### Use signals (synchronization aid)

There are many synchronization aid tools since JDK 1.5 works like a signal.

[CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

This object provides a counter(can be set only once and count down many times). This counter allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

[CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

This is another useful signal that allows a set of threads to all wait for each other to reach a common barrier point.

### more tools

More tools could be found in JDK `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: i think this is over kill. if you have given a job to a thread/pool, and hav isolatd that task, can just add a attribute to check.

Comment: @tgkprog An attribute is a variable belong to a object, if you mean an attribute is added to a task, I agree that is ok. The main point I was talking about is we should not use an attribute from a thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.isAlive` method, see API: "A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died". That is in task2 run() you test task1.isAlive()

To see task1 from task2 you need to pass it as an argument to task2's construtor, or make tasks fields instead of local vars

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use the following..
task1.join();
task2.join();
task3.join();
task4.join();
// and then check every thread by using isAlive() method
e.g : task1.isAlive(); 
if it return false means that thread had completed it's task
otherwise it will true
```

Comment: isAlive() here seems unnecessary; by definition the thread has terminated for join() to return.

Comment: I know that but if you want to check thread is running or not then isAlive() will be used

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your exact needs, but some Java application frameworks have handy abstractions for dealing with individual units of work or "jobs". The Eclipse Rich Client Platform comes to mind with its Jobs API. Although it may be overkill.

For plain old Java, look at Future, Callable and Executor.